# SQL Server 2005 -Join based on criteria in table column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005, what is the most efficient way to join the two tables in the following scenario ?

The number of records in each table could be fairly large about 200000 say.

The only way I can currently think of doing this is with the use of cursors and some dynamic SQL for each item which will clearly be very inefficient.

I have two tables - a `PERSON` table and a `SEARCHITEMS` table. The `SEARCHITEMS` table contains a column with some simple criteria which is to be used when matching records with the `PERSON` table. The criteria can reference any column in the `PERSON` table.

For example given the following tables :

`PERSON` table

```
PERSONID   FIRSTNAME LASTNAME GENDER AGE ... VARIOUS OTHER COLUMNS
1          Fred      Bloggs   M      16
....
200000     Steve     Smith    M      18
```

`SEARCHITEMS` table

```
ITEMID         DESCRIPTION      SEARCHCRITERIA 
1              Males            GENDER = 'M'
2              Aged 16          AGE=16
3              Some Statistic   {OTHERCOLUMN >= SOMEVALUE AND OTHERCOLUMN < SOMEVALUE}
....
200000         Males Aged 16    GENDER = 'M' AND AGE = 16
```

`RESULTS` table should contain something like this :

```
ITEMID         DESCRIPTION       PERSONID    LASTNAME

1              Males             1           Bloggs
1              Males             200000      Smith
2              Aged 16           1           Bloggs
....
200000         Males Aged 16     1           Bloggs
```

It would be nice to be able to just do something like

```
INSERT INTO RESULTSTABLE
  SELECT * 
  FROM PERSON P
  LEFT JOIN SEARCHITEMS SI ON (APPLY SI.SEARCHCRITERIA TO P)
```

But I can't see a way of making this work. Any help or ideas appreciated.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly? Is the requirement just to join these 2 tables?

Comment: The requirement is to insert the results from any matching records into a results table - it doesn't necessarily need to be using a join it just needs to be efficient - I see the join ultimately being the most efficient if it could be achieved.

Comment: I think we should have a middle table between person and search item because the result table's size as it's currently described will explode out of proportion. I have thought about it and I couldn't come up with a better solution then using a cursor, unless you know all search criteria combinations (which I highly doubt).

Comment: Yes good point about the middle table. Unfortunatley I don't know all the combinations.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing that the SEARCHITEMS table is non-relational by nature, it seems that the cursor and dynamic SQL solution is the only workable one. Of course this will be quite slow and I would "pre-calculate" the results to make it somewhat bearable.

To do this create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE MATCHEDITEMS(
    ITEMID int NOT NULL
       CONSTRAINT fkMatchedSearchItem 
       FOREIGN KEY 
       REFERENCES SEARCHITEMS(ITEMID), 
    PERSONID int 
       CONSTRAINT fkMatchedPerson 
       FOREIGN KEY 
       REFERENCES PERSON(PERSONID)
       CONSTRAINT pkMatchedItems 
       PRIMARY KEY (ITEMID, PERSONID)
       )
```

The table will contain a lot of data, but considering it only stores 2 int columns the footprint on disk will be small.

To update this table you create the following triggers:

- a trigger on the SEARCHITEMS table which will populate the MATCHEDITEMS table whenever a rule is changed or added.
- a trigger on the PERSON table which will run the rules on the updated or added PERSON records.

Results can then simply be presented by joining the 3 tables.

```
SELECT m.ITEMID, m.DESCRIPTION, m.PERSONID, p.LASTNAME
FROM MATCHEDITEMS m
JOIN PERSON p
  ON m.PERSONID = p.PERSONID
JOIN SEARCHITEMS s
  ON m.ITEMID = s.ITEMID
```

Comment: +1 for coming up with a sensible workaround.  I don't think there exists a better solution, and at least this would be kept updated with the triggers once the initial load was done.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this. I hadn't thought of the idea of using triggers to update the table.

Answer (score -1):

You could build your TSQL dynamically, and then execute it with [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).